# Xcode 7 - Unable to validate your application

Tags: xcode, validation, app-store, xcode7, ipa

When i upload my app to app store, i've had a problem:

```
Unable to validate your application:
The path '/var/folders/hm/.../MyApp.ipa' does not contain a file
```

I have another error:

```
Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for sfnt2woff
```

I've added:

```
<key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
<array>
    <string>MacOSX</string>
</array>
```

in my plist file but it doesn't work.

Any solution?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution. In my application, a library called "ionicons" has been used. I just simply remove the sfnt2woff file in lib/ionicons/builder/scripts/ and the validation works.

Answer (score 11):

Have the same problem. Just delete some .bundle resource from "Bundle Resources" in Build Phases in Xcode project. See here:

[image]

Comment: Yes! That was it! I accidentally had a dSYM on Copy Bundle Resources. Removed it and it worked.

Comment: For me, this was caused by Urban Airship's ```Airship``` and ```AirshipKit``` folders being in Copy Bundle Resources. I removed those and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Worked for me too! When added Urbanairship, it was added to Copy Bundle Resources. Thanks

Comment: This helped me out, i had dragged a framework into the build phase for one of my app extensions.

Answer (score 7):

Setting "Enable bit code" to NO worked for me

[image]

Also:

1. Clean build folder
2. `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
3. Restart xcode.

If you do not wish to rebuild, you can untick theses checkbox:

[image: include app symbols/include bitcode]

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was asked for permission to access something in my Keychain. I mistakenly clicked 'deny'. Once I re-archived the app again and granted it the permission, it works.

Answer (score -1):

For the benefit of others like me: I had a similar problem with an old version of sparkle that didn't include the info.plist in the framework.

Check all your frameworks; They now also need an info.plist with these settings.